# Unit testing issue c# object getProperties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a c# class that gets object property names.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class Parser<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Parse(T item)
    {
        const BindingFlags flag = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;

        return item.GetType().GetProperties(flag).Select(p => p.Name);
    }
}
```

I want to test this methot.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var parser = new Parser<MyClass>();
        var names = parser.Parse(new MyClass()).ToArray();

        Assert.IsTrue(names[1] == "Name");
    }
```

But this throws an exception **System.NullReferenceException**. But I put breakpoint and see `names` array have two items.

`Assert.IsTrue(names[1] == "Name");` row throws exception. But is has 2 items.

> Test 'M:ParsProejct.TestsClass.TestMethod.' failed: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Why are you using `Assert.IsTrue` (which will never give you much information) rather than `Assert.AreEqual` to start with? I doubt that it will fix things, but it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: I tried `Assert.AreEqual(names[0], "Name");` now, but did not work.

Comment: Right. But it's something you should use (the other way round) in future. For now, you need to work out what's null. To improve this question, you should a) make it a [mcve]; b) include the full stack trace rather than just the message.

Comment: What are you using to run your tests? NUnit asserts can throw a NullReferenceException if they are not run within an NUnit runner. I would recommend running in nunit3-console.exe to give you more information.

Comment: I am using NUnit